# How to check lowercased URLs and redirect if they're valid with Lambda@Edge

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda-edge

I've got some old URLs that used to use capital letters for people's names and such, but now I've updated my site to just lowercase characters in the URLs of every page. So, I'd like to redirect people if they happen to have clicked on an old link, or typed a capital letter by accident.

I also check removing a trailing slash. Here's the code I currently use on the front end. I was hoping to switch over to using Lambda@Edge (My website is on S3 and distributed via CloudFront) for that check and redirect.

Here's the JS function I'm using on the front end:

```
var newUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase().replace(/\/$/, '')

loadIfChanged(newUrl)

function loadIfChanged (newUrl) {
  if (newUrl != location.href) {
    fetch(newUrl, {method: 'HEAD'}).then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 200) return window.location = newUrl
    }).catch(function (error) {
      return console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

How might I write that in a Lambda@Edge function?

Maybe something like this:

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  // Lowercase the URL and trim off a trailing slash if there is one
  var path = event.Records[0].cf.request.uri.toLowerCase().replace(/\/$/, '')

  // How to do a fetch here? var ok = fetch()

  if (ok) {
    const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
      headers: {
        location: [{
          key: 'Location',
          value: `https://example.com/${path}`,
        }],
      },
    }
    return response
  } else {
    return event.Records[0].cf.request
  }
}
```

Can Lambda@Edge functions even do I/O?

And, importantly, can this Lambda@Edge function run only on 404s?

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote should work, but I think better implementation would be to simply change the URI in the **OriginRequest** Lambda function. The code is as simple as :

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request'];
    request['uri'] = "anything";

    return request;
```

An interesting detail to note here is that CF will cache the result of modified URI against the original URI. So if a request comes again for the original URI, CloudFront will return the response directly from the cache.

**Why Origin Request?**

1. Because it is triggered only on cache misses
2. It helps get the benefit of cache described above

**Why this way is better as compared to what you proposed?**
***If you decide to go via the above mentioned approach***, following is the request flow:
For non-cached content:

```
User -> CF -> Lambda -> S3 -> Final response to the user
```

For cached content:

```
User -> CF -> Final response to the user
```

***Whereas if you use Lambda to generate 301*** the flow would be:
For non-cached content:

```
User -> CF -> Lambda -> User -> CF -> Lambda -> S3 -> Final response to the user
```

For cached content:

```
User -> CF(cf returns 301) -> User -> CF -> Final response to the user
```

So you get two advantages in this approach :

1. Lesser latency for your user.
2. Lesser lambda invocation which means lesser bill for you.

**For your second question**, I do not think there is any way to invoke Lambda@Edge only for 404s as of now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, essentially, I'm enforcing URL format, by lowercasing them, and stripping off trailing commas (which is what I do), any time CloudFront needs to hit the origin. That response is then cashed whether it's a 404 or not?

Comment: Haa! I tired this and now fonts and images are missing. Guess I forgot about Camel cased JavaScript files and images with capital letters in them and font files. Plus the URL doesn't get rewritten, it stays the way the user typed it. The redirect is needed it seems.